# How to determine if a Shape exists in a cell in a range?

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I exported/copied a sheet of data. That data sheet has checkmark shapes in some of the fields, representing active. I am trying to identify those shapes and if true put a "Yes" in the column next to them and "No" if not.

I borrowed this code for a Function which is in Module - Image Check  - that I call from a cmdbtn "Load" that formats this sheet of data before bringing it into my workbook.

```vb
Function Check4Image(CellToCheck As Range) As Integer    
    ' Return 1 if image exists in cell, 0 if not
    Dim wShape As shape
    For Each wShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If wShape.TopLeftCell = CellToCheck Then
            Check4Image = 1
            'Check4Image = 1
        Else
            Check4Image = 0
        End If
    Next wShape
End Function
```

Script for the Call

```
Dim proshaperng As Range
Dim proshapecel
Dim proshapeloc As Range
Dim shapeint As Integer

Set proshaperng = Range("F4", "F" & shapeint)   
Set proshapeloc = Range("F4", "F" & shapeint).Cells

For Each proshapecel In proshaperng
    proshapeloc = Range(proshapecel.Address)
    'proshapeloc.Select
        
    Call Check4Image(proshapeloc)
    If Check4Image(proshapeloc) = 1 Then
        proshapeloc.Offset(0, 1) = "Yes"
    Else
        proshapeloc.Offset(0, 1) = "No"
    End If
Next proshapecel
```

I tried

1. In standard Excel Fx =Check4Image(Cell) and this returns the "1" I expect when the cell has a shape in it
2. Changing the function to a Variant or another variable type Due to a Run Time error 13 Type Mismatch

My thought is that it wants a range and when I try to give it a range it gives me object errors. This may be because the workbook /sheet I'm copying is open during this process.

This worked but for a specific cell reference:

```
Set proshapeloc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ProcessList").Range("F4")
```

Comment: You haven't actually said what the problem is - you suggest the function works? One thing is that you should I think be using the `Address` property in your comparison.

Comment: The problem is that when the function is called I get a mismatch error as the code is going through the Function: 
For Each wShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If wShape.TopLeftCell = CellToCheck Then - Error Occurs type Mismatch

The Function when ran from excel when you just put a static cell in  = Check4Image(F4) will return the "1" when a shape is in F4. But for some reason i can't get it to pass a dynamic range of variables in the For Each Loop

Comment: What do you mean by a "dynamic range of variables" - please illustrate how you are trying to do this?

Comment: Thanks SJR, I was trying to pass a range of cells through the function to have each one evaluated independently but each time it was either mismatching or not evaluating the cell address. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a different test:

```
If wShape.TopLeftCell = CellToCheck Then
```

...this only compares the cell *values*, not whether they're the same cell.

Something like this would work:

```vb
'return any image in the passed cell (or Nothing if none)
Function FindImage(CellToCheck As Range) As Shape
    Dim wShape As Shape, addr
    addr = CellToCheck.Address
    For Each wShape In CellToCheck.Parent.Shapes 'more flexible
        If wShape.TopLeftCell.Address = addr Then
            Set FindImage = wShape
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next wShape
End Function

Sub Tester()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A1:A10").Cells
        c.Offset(0, 1) = IIf(FindImage(c) Is Nothing, "No", "Yes")
    Next c
End Sub
```