How to check if a cell contains a shape?
I want to check if a particular cell has a shape, eg. B7.
if it doesnt exist, make new shape at B7 (B7.top, B7.left).
if it exists, move X columns to the right and make new shape
I tried checking by following code, but it doesnt work, because I dont think it can search this way:
rg = Activesheet.Range("B7")
Do While Not rg.Value = vbNullString
rg = rg.Offset(0, 6)
Loop



Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65837352/7599798

Give this a try:
Sub AddOrMoveShape()
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim shapeExists As Boolean
    Dim colOffset As Integer
    
    ' Starting position
    Set rg = ActiveSheet.Range("B7")
    colOffset = 0
    
    Do
        shapeExists = False
        ' Check if a shape exists at the current cell position
        For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            If shp.TopLeftCell.Address = rg.Offset(0, colOffset).Address Then
                shapeExists = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next shp
        
        ' If no shape exists at the current position, create a new shape
        If Not shapeExists Then
            Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
                rg.Offset(0, colOffset).Left, _
                rg.Offset(0, colOffset).Top, _
                50, 50)
            shp.Name = "MyShape" & (colOffset \ 6 + 1) ' Optional: Naming the shape
            Exit Do
        End If
       
        ' Move to the next position to the right
        colOffset = colOffset + 6
    Loop
End Sub


Thanks @W_O_L_F for the direction and for reminding me of the .address function of the cell
I simplified the code to the following:
shape_exists = False For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes     If shp.TopLeftCell.Address = rg.Offset(0, col_offset).Address Then         shape_exists = True         col_offset = col_offset + 6     Else         Exit For     End If Next shp
and then called a separate sub for creating shapes

separate sub with rg.offset(0,col_offset) as input

Create a Reference to the Left-Most Shapeless Cell in a Row (With Offset)
Main
Sub Test()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const LEFT_MOST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B7"
    Const CELL_COLUMN_OFFSET As Long = 6
    
    ' Define the main objects.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim cell As Range: Set cell = ws.Range(LEFT_MOST_CELL_ADDRESS)

    ' Return the addresses of the top left cells of each shape
    ' of the worksheet in the keys of a dictionary.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = DictShapeAddresses(ws)
    
    ' Reference the left-most shapeless cell.
    Dim shapelessCell As Range
    If dict Is Nothing Then ' no shapes found
        Set shapelessCell = cell
    Else ' at least one shape found
        Set shapelessCell = RefFirstShapelessCellInRow( _
            dict, cell, CELL_COLUMN_OFFSET)
        If shapelessCell Is Nothing Then ' should not happen!
            MsgBox "All cells in row """ & cell.Row & """ have shapes!", _
                vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
     
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "The left-most shapeless cell is """ & shapelessCell.Address(0, 0) _
        & """.", vbInformation

End Sub

Help
Function DictShapeAddresses(ws As Worksheet) As Object
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        dict(shp.TopLeftCell.Address(0, 0)) = Empty
    Next shp
    Set DictShapeAddresses = dict
End Function

Function RefFirstShapelessCellInRow( _
    shapeAddresses As Object, _
    firstCell As Range, _
    Optional CellColumnOffset As Long = 1) _
As Range
    If CellColumnOffset < 1 Then Exit Function
    Dim c As Long
    With firstCell.EntireRow
        For c = firstCell.Column To .Columns.Count Step CellColumnOffset
            If Not shapeAddresses.Exists(.Cells(c).Address(0, 0)) Then
                Set RefFirstShapelessCellInRow = .Cells(c)
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Function


Just for curiosity: Any reason you use late binding for the dictionary?

I guess, I'm tired of explaining about creating a reference to the library and why the code fails with a compile error when this is not regarded. Also, it would take a considerable amount of time to explain how it works and some people aren't even interested but may still use the code successfully. Of course, there is another side to it that I wouldn't discuss here. Feel free to share your opinion on the matter.

Ok, fair enough.
